# Random creating binary ID

Tags: matlab, rfid

Could you help me?
I have n = 10 (ten tags) with 8 bits value each. Every tag should have one randomly created 1's in ID (for example 00000100, 01000000). How can I do this in Matlab?

Comment: You need to show some code and clarify your question.  As it is written this question should be closed as it is not providing a clear example of the problem

Comment: number_tags= 10. a want to create 10 vectors with 8 bits. Also I want to randomly choose number 1 in each tag. For example:

Tag1 = [00100000];
Tag2 = [00000100];
Tag3 = [01000000];

Comment: How about you create a [random integer](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/random.html) and [turn it into a binary number](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/bin.html)

Comment: I can not do it. If you can write a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
n = 10;
r = 8;
k = randi(r,1,n);
Tag  = zeros(r,n);
Tag(r*(find(k)-1) + k)=1;
Tag = Tag';
```

So:

```
k =

8     8     5     2     2     3     7     3     7     2

Tag =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now each **row** - your Tag. For example, `Tag1 = Tag(1,:)`.

In this case lets find needed result:
if we need only logical values (1 if there is 1 in any row, and 0 if there is no any 1 in column) we have to add this:

```
result = sum(Tag);
result(find(result))=1
result =
0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
```

Number of ones and zeros:

```
c1 = sum(result);
c0 = numel(result) - c1;
```

Comment: I want for bigger number of tags. And as you can see does not working for Tag3

Comment: In your question `n=10` so it works. But ok i will make it for any n. For `Tag3` works too, of course, if you add `Tag3 = zeros(1,8)` similarly.

Comment: Friend, could you see this:

clear all
clc;

c = 16;
r = 8;
n= 10;

c = zeros(n,c);

I want to every row in this matric has one random 1 on some position. OK?

Comment: @NikolaC ok, try this. Is this you want?

Comment: I saw that some row has double values of 1?

Comment: For example last row has four value of 1. Could you see?

Comment: I wrote `every column` ) ok, if you need rows just use `Tag = Tag';` after all and you'll get it!

Comment: But if I do Tag = Tag'; I change size of matrix. Now is 10x8 instead 8x10

Comment: So, change `r` and `n` values. I will edit my answer

Comment: OK. Thank you. One more question. @Mikhail_Sam how can i calculate final bits. Please look example:

     [0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0]
     [0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
     [0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]

Result:
     [0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0]

Comment: I want if you can to write how to calculate this result?

Comment: @NikolaC is this ok?

Comment: Great @Mikhail_Sam. I want one more thing. How to calculate number of '1' and '0' in result?

Comment: OKEY) @NikolaC look at my answer

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail_Sam. You help me a lot

Comment: @NikolaC can you then accept my answer? )

Comment: Of course. Sorry and thank you